# domain name with same netbios name

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, domain-name

Hi In a bit of an odd situation so looking for some advice

I have a MS domain running on Server 2012r2 using 2012 function levels but I need to change it's name which I'm pretty sure I have a handle on.

The issue is the current domain name is one word (for this example I will call it Jeff) not Jeff.local or anything just Jeff so the netbios name is also Jeff which is fine I guess (this has just been upgraded from at least 2003 it's probably older).

I need to change the domain to Jeff.JeffCorp.com but I was thinking of keeping the netbios name as just Jeff on it's own.

Would keeping the same netbios name while going through the domain name renaming procedure cause any headaches or should it "just work" or should I consider changing the netbios name to something else (e.g Jeff.JeffCorp)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id leave it as Jeff, NetBIOS names should be single label names of 15 characters or less.

there are a couple of article here on domain renames,

https://techjourney.net/rename-ad-domain-name-in-windows-server-2012/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781575(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see there being any issue keeping the same netbios name but I just wanted a second opinion